# what happens when you pass android systemclock.sleep(long) a negative parameter

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Expectedly, this `SystemClock.sleep(paramMaybeNegative)` is being used in a multi-threaded context, if that is relevant. The negative would come from an uninitialized object property in some yet unforseen circumstance.

Here is the documentation regarding what I am asking about:
[developer.android.com:SystemClock.sleep(long)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#sleep%28long%29).  It doesn't mention an exception or forever or something else that might be expected.

Putting this question here to remember to answer it later and handle the consequences in some code I am writing, as much as in hopes someone knows what to expect already and wants to type about it before I get to (super-informative and helpfully interesting factoids about SystemClocks also welcome:).

Comment: I think down voting because I wanted feedback before trying it was harsh

Comment: I get the down vote maybe for involving stackoverflow in code writing.  Unfortunately unfun of the internet and SO, especially given no reasoning behinde the dv

Comment: I believe you got downvote, because you could have easily answered your question and then you might have asked why this is the behavior

Comment: yeah, I guess easier to type up and run test try than to type up question.  shame, I will try to flag to delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It calls `Thread.sleep(millis)` which throws an `IllegalArgumentException`.

You can find out by reading the src code, or by trying out.

Comment: my emulator throws similar error, error stack trace info "googlesource.com: android VMThread IllegalArgumentException" search getting https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/a7752f4d22097346dd7849b92b9f36d0a0a7a8f3/libdvm/src/main/java/java/lang/VMThread.java shows sleep method is a 'native' method and doesnt mention any ArgumentException.  Unless I am looking at a wrong source file there, it is beyond normal dvelepor opensource.  stupid hypercritical stackoverflow, u suk

Comment: Yes i meant IllegalArgumentException, was a typing error. fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

From reading and guessing at source code running in emulator I would expect it to not throw error and act like a `SystemClock.sleep(0)`; it throws to logcat and crashes app:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeout arguments out of range
    at java.lang.VMThread.sleep(Native Method)
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

I am as likely as not looking at wrong source file.

Comment: other re-search did find platform/libcore/+/a7752f4d22097346dd7849b92b9f36d0a0a7a8f3/libdvm/src/main/java/java/lang/VMThread.java where an argument conditional throws similar mentioned exception.  So much outside/-down build process; so little time